# How to remove last letter from a string if there is any in R

Tags: r, string

I'd like to remove the last character of a string if there is any letter at the end of it.

sample vector is:

```
string <- c("L_3_A_L_3_1b",  "L_3_A_L_3_1e",  "L_3_A_L_3_1h", "RL_3_C_RL_3_9", "SL_3_A_SL_3_2")
```

I'd like to drop the last letter as:

```
> string
[1] "L_3_A_L_3_1"  "L_3_A_L_3_1"  "L_3_A_L_3_1"  "RL_3_C_RL_3_9" "SL_3_A_SL_3_2"
```

ANy thoughts?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can specify the letters (`[A-Za-z]`) specifically (as the OP's post is `if there is any letter at the end of it`) to match at the end (`$`) of the string and replace with blank (`""`)

```
sub("[A-Za-z]$", "", string)
#[1] "L_3_A_L_3_1"   "L_3_A_L_3_1"   "L_3_A_L_3_1" 
#[4] "RL_3_C_RL_3_9" "SL_3_A_SL_3_2"
```

---

Or use `trimws`

```
trimws(string, whitespace = '[A-Za-z]', which = 'right')
#[1] "L_3_A_L_3_1"   "L_3_A_L_3_1"   "L_3_A_L_3_1"   "RL_3_C_RL_3_9" "SL_3_A_SL_3_2"
```

Comment: $ tells to look at the last character whether it is letter, I guess,

Comment: @amisos55 i updated with description.  Yes `$` speficies the end of string

Comment: amisos55, a good regex reference explains a lot of small regex-isms like that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3358272. The biggest distinction is that most single-backslash references in regex need double-backslash in R; for example, regex `\D` becomes `\\D` in R.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the negative character class `\\D`, which matches anything that is *not* a digit:

```
sub("\\D$", "", string)
[1] "L_3_A_L_3_1"   "L_3_A_L_3_1"   "L_3_A_L_3_1"   "RL_3_C_RL_3_9" "SL_3_A_SL_3_2"
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You probably know that you can accept an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(stringr)
str_remove(string,"[a-zA-Z]$")
```